# Java read JSON input stream

Tags: java, json, tcp, inputstream

I am programming a simple TCP server in Java that is listening on some URL on some port. Some client (not in Java) sends a JSON message to the server, something like this `{'message':'hello world!', 'test':555}`. I accept the message an try to get the JSON (I am thinking to use GSON library).

```
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
```

But how can I get the message from input stream? I tried to use `ObjectInputStream`, but as far as I understood it waits serialized data and JSON is no serialized.

Comment: JSON is a string until you use a library to decode it to a java object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap it with a [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and start reading the data from it:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))) {
    String line;
    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    String content = sb.toString();
    //as example, you can see the content in console output
    System.out.println(content);
}
```

Once you have it as a String, parse it with a library like Gson or Jackson.

Comment: I feel like your code may introduce partial read or reading more than one message in single go problem. Can you please verify

Answer (score 0):

```
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        int ch;
        boolean run = true;
        try {
            while(run) {
                ch = reader.read();
                if(ch == -1) { break; }
                buffer.append((char) ch);
                if(isJSONValid(buffer.toString())){ run = false;}
            }
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            //handle exception
        }



private boolean isJSONValid(String test) {
        try {
            new JSONObject(test);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            try {
                new JSONArray(test);
            } catch (JSONException ex1) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```